# Qt : images won't animate with QParallelAnimationGroup

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I have a problem with Qt concerning animations. I have a QParallelAnimationGroup named animation_group, and I create a QPropertyAnimation* when I want to add an animation to the group. But when I call animation_group.start(), nothing happens (the QLabels in square_table should be animated). The only thing I see is that the QLabels appear where they should be (the start position) but don't move to the end position. This is really weird. You can find my code below:

```
void GridView::select_animation(int start_x, int start_y, int end_x, int end_y)
{
    QPropertyAnimation* anim = new QPropertyAnimation(square_table[start_x][start_y], "geometry");
    connect(anim, SIGNAL(finished()), anim, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    anim->setDuration(4000);
    // xtable_to_position and ytable_to_position are member functions giving a valid int.
    anim->setStartValue(QRect(xtable_to_position(start_x), ytable_to_position(start_y), square_size, square_size));
    anim->setEndValue(QRect(xtable_to_position(end_x), ytable_to_position(end_y), square_size, square_size));
    animation_group.addAnimation(anim);
    square_table[end_x][end_y] = square_table[start_x][start_y];
}

void GridView::animate()
{
    animation_group.start();
    animation_group.clear();
}
```

I don't know what's happening. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should not call `clear()`, it eliminates all animations.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works (I just wanted that the group become empty after the animations)